# 2x2 Matrix with a 2x2 matrix as the M_11 element

Tags: equations, matrices

I am trying to make a 2x2 matrix that has as a first element another 2x2 matrix

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\rvline}{\hspace*{-\arraycolsep}\vline\hspace*{-\arraycolsep}}
\begin{equation}
\sbox0{$\begin{matrix} \boldsymbol{\mathrm{P}}& \rvline&\boldsymbol{\mathrm{S}}  \\\hline \boldsymbol{\mathrm{S}}& \rvline& \boldsymbol{\mathrm{S}} \end{matrix}$}
%
\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\hat{H}}} =\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
\usebox{0}&\makebox[\wd0]{\boldsymbol{\mathrm{S}}}\\
\hline
  \vphantom{\usebox{0}}\makebox[\wd0]{\boldsymbol{\mathrm{S}}}&\makebox[\wd0]{\boldsymbol{\mathrm{S}}}
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}
```

for some reason I get an error when I compile: ! Extra }, or forgotten $.\math@atom #1#2->\binrel@ {#1}\binrel@@ {#2} ...0}&\makebox[\wd0]{\boldsymbol{\mathrm{S}}}

Comment: Nope, this code doesn't give that error as the first one. It will complain about `missing $ inserted`, because the arguments of `\makebox` are in text mode. Everything else is a follow-up error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not easy to read. For instance, instance, instead of `\boldsymbol{\mathrm{S}}}`, just write `\mathbf{S}`. Making these changes, replacing `\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\hat{H}}}` with `\widehat{\mathbf{H}}`, dropping a couple of unnecessary `\makebox` instructions, and remembering that `\mathbf{S}` has to occur in math mode -- as already noted by [@campa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/82917/campa) -- leads to the following outcome:

[image]

I trust that this is (close to) what you're trying to achieve.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % 'mathtools' package not needed for this example
\newcommand{\rvline}{\hspace*{-\arraycolsep}\vline\hspace*{-\arraycolsep}}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\sbox0{$\begin{matrix} 
       \mathbf{P} & \rvline & \mathbf{S}  \\
       \hline 
       \mathbf{S} & \rvline & \mathbf{S} 
    \end{matrix}$}
%
\widehat{\mathbf{H}} =
\left[ \begin{array}{c|c}
   \usebox{0}                       & \makebox[\wd0]{$\mathbf{S}$} \\
   \hline
   \vphantom{\usebox{0}} \mathbf{S} & \mathbf{S}
\end{array} \right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, prompted by a comment posted by @campa: The code shown above works correctly; however, that's due in no small part because it uses `\widehat` instead of `\hat`. To make the code more robust, while still following the OP's original `\sbox`/`\usebox`/`\makebox` path, it's necessary to delay running `\sbox0` until just before the start of the `array` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\newcommand{\rvline}{\hspace*{-\arraycolsep}\vline\hspace*{-\arraycolsep}}
\newcommand\PSSSmat{%  % define a macro that creates the small matrix
  \begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}  % use 'array', not 'matrix'
    \mathbf{P} & \mathbf{S} \\ \hline \mathbf{S} & \mathbf{S}
  \end{array}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\hat{\mathbf{H}} =
\sbox0{$\PSSSmat$} % set "box 0" just before array env.
\left[ \begin{array}{c|c}
   \usebox{0}  &  \makebox[\wd0]{$\mathbf{S}$}\\
   \hline
   \vphantom{\usebox{0}} \mathbf{S} & \mathbf{S}
\end{array} \right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Aside: Note that it's possible to use an `array` environment instead of a `matrix` environment in the definition of the small matrix; an advantage is that one no longer has to create an extra column to hold `\rvline` instructions.

Comment: `mathtools` isn't strictly necessary but with it you can use `\mathmakebox` instead of putting the argument of `\makebox` in `$...$`. That was how I was writing the answer `:-)`

Comment: Funny side-comment: have you tried the code with `\hat` instead of `\widehat`? I was quite puzzled `:-D`

Comment: @campa - Indeed! It would appear that `\hat{\mathbf{H}}` creates a new "Box 0", whereas `\widehat{\mathbf{H}}` does not. This indicates that the OP's use of `\sbox`, `\usebox`, and `\makebox` isn't all that robust. I'll think about providing a more robust solution.

Comment: Yep, the redefinition of the math accents in `amsmath` uses `\box\z@`. Interesting, in lines 756-757 the redefinition for `\widehat` and `\widetilde` is commented out but still present in the source code.